# Why we are using static_cast to NULL

Tags: c++, static-cast

When I try to study QP/CPP code I came across below line.

```
QTimeEvt *t; 
// ...
if (t == static_cast<QTimeEvt *>(0)) {
```

Why they are doing static_cast of 0?
If they want to check NULL we can do that directly right?

This source code you can find out in

http://www.state-machine.com/qpcpp/qf__time_8cpp_source.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yeah, that's unnecessary, though it may be mandated by some style guide for "clarity", or it may be there to silence an overzealous static analysis tool.

Of course, nowadays, we'd just write `nullptr` and leave it at that.

Comment: @M.M: Somewhat less preferable.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit whats the problem with `!t` ?

Comment: @GilsonPJ: Not self-documenting, doesn't hard-error when you change what `t` is (accidentally or otherwise) etc etc. (I'm being a bit picky. I like to _use_ the type system, though. Its job is to aid in ensuring program correctness, and writing out `== nullptr` is hardly expensive.)

Comment: how?? why you are telling `==nullptr` checking is expensive? for deletion it may be correct but in this kind of scenario how `nullptr` checking becomes expensive?

Comment: @GilsonPJ: It doesn't; I didn't say it does.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit thanks +1 for the quick answer

Comment: @GilsonPJ :i don't like (!t). The reason being is the expression (t) is not boolean, it is pointer. I prefer only applying !, &&  & || only to boolean expressions (and that means if they are not boolean expressions, they are rewritten so they are).

Answer (score 4):

The idiomatic way to write

```
QTimeEvt *t; 
// ...
if (t == static_cast<QTimeEvt *>(0)) {
```

… is

```
QTimeEvt* t; 
// ...
if( !t ) {
```

---

Or you can write it as

```
if( not t ) {
```

… although you can also write

```
if( t == nullptr ) {
```

… or, ¹C++03-style,

```
if( t == 0 ) {
```

---

There's no need for the cast.

It's just verbiage consuming the reader's time.

<sup>*Notes:*

¹ If the `<stddefs.h>` header is included one can write [`NULL`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL) instead of `0` where a nullpointer is required. With a modern implementation `NULL` might even be defined as `nullptr`.</sup>

Comment: `if( not t )` Is this commonplace?

Comment: Didn't know `NULL` can be `nullptr` since C++11 — good to find out!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I don't know about how common it is. As far as I know there is no global code inspection service, as Google Code View once provided. I do know that with Visual C++ you have to include the C header `<iso646.h>` to use `not`, that is, MSVC is not standard-conforming here. I use a forced include to make it more conformant.

Comment: That's pretty grim.

Comment: Yep. But then, by default MSVC doesn't even support standard `main` for its most common use… Heh. :)